# Updating an open Scene from another Scene

Tags: javafx

I'm trying to send value from  Scene A to Scene B. any Idea how to get it done? Also, without opening scene B if it already opened. Thanks

Comment: What type of values do you want to send?  Also please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Possible duplicate [Passing Parameters Javafx FXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Parameters JavaFX FXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what type of value it is and if the Scene's are in different classes. But if you were sending the value of a `Text` object in one scene to another `Text` object in another scene for instance, then using something like this may help:

```
Text sceneAvalue = new Text("Scene A value");
Text sceneBvalue = new Text(sceneAvalue.getText());
//add sceneBValue to Scene B however you usually add components to a scene
```

Comment: This answer is totally irrelevant to the question asked.